# Openstack NovaClient : Error while launching an instance using servers.create()

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova, novaclient

I tried to spawn a cirros instance using nova python client with below api call,

```
server = nova.servers.create(name = "cirros_vm",
                             image = image.id,
                             flavor = flavor.id )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
novaclient.exceptions.BadRequest: Multiple possible networks
found, use a Network ID to be more specific. (HTTP 400)
(Request-ID: req-c3aba1d2-23e9-4751-badc-60142286232e)
```

This is because I an having multiple networks inside my tenant.The help documentation shows that the optional `nics` argument should be used.

```
 :param nics:  (optional extension) an ordered list of nics to be
                  added to this server, with information about
                  connected networks, fixed ips, port etc.
```

But I am not able to figure out how to pass network ids to this api.
When I give network ids as an ordered list,

```
server = nova.servers.create(name = "api_cir_test",
                             image = image.id,
                             flavor = flavor.id,
                             nics=[ network1.id, network2.id])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Below are the details of variables used:

```
nova is an object of Client in module novaclient.v1_1.client 
image = nova.images.find(name="cirros")
flavor =nova.flavors.find(name="m1.small")
network =nova.networks.find(label="test_net")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nics` argument requires the same information you would supply on the `nova boot` command line...which means it accepts things other than network ids (you can pass in explicit neutron port IDs, for example, or you can provide information about fixed ip addresses).  The `nics` argument needs an ordered list of *dictionaries*, such as:

```
server = nova.servers.create(name = "api_cir_test",
                             image = image.id,
                             flavor = flavor.id,
                             nics=[{'net-id': network1.id},
                                   {'net-id': network2.id}])
```

That should successfully create your server.

Comment: Can u mention available keys in nics param. if i want to pass `port-id` what should be the key in the dictionary.

Comment: [Use the source, Luke!](https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/master/novaclient/v2/servers.py#L514)

Comment: Thanks @larsks. What I have used is `server = nova.servers.create(name = "api_cir_test",
                             image = image.id,
                             flavor = flavor.id,
                             nics=[{'net-id': network1.id},
                                   {'port-id': port_id } ]  , block_dev_mapping = { 'vdb':'8b7e3ab4-18a3-49d6-8f7d-767ca30809c2' , 'vdc':'6933e0cd-df22-4bab-b870-9365935956bb' } )`